# Check which edge attributes exist (NetworkX)

Tags: python, openstreetmap, networkx

I'm using OSMNX to load an OpenStreetMap file of a city into NetworkX. Is there any way for me to see which attributes are stored in the graph? I believe OSMNX might for instance store the length of a street, or the type of road. I want to know what the names of the attributes are that I can access.

Comment: You can use [`get_edge_data`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.get_edge_data.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could either display the edges to see what's in them:

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, California', network_type='drive')
print(G.edges(keys=True, data=True))
```

Or you could use OSMnx to [convert the edges to a GeoDataFrame](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.save_load.graph_to_gdfs) and inspect its columns:

```
edge_attributes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False).columns
print(edge_attributes)
```

Finally, note that you can configure which OSM attributes OSMnx attaches to graph nodes and edges by passing the `useful_tags_way` or `useful_tags_node` arguments to [ox.config()](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils.config).