# How can I get lon-lat coordinates from node id(OSMnx)?

Tags: python, openstreetmap

I am new to this osmnx python lib. 
I want to know angle deviation between points.
So, I tried to know lon-lan coordinates from OSM points ID.
But I cannot do it.
Anyone to tell me how to get coordinates from OSM points ID?

Comment: Please read [ask], and also [mcve].  Show us what you did, what you have, and what you want.  "How do I X?" questions are asking for a book, only ask for what you really need.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how to use [OSMnx](http://geoffboeing.com/2016/11/osmnx-python-street-networks/) to retrieve the lat-long coordinates of a set of OSM node IDs in some graph. First create your graph. As it is a networkx multidigraph, you can use any of the built-in networkx methods [to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698352/storing-and-accessing-node-attributes-python-networkx) [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23233127/how-to-get-values-from-specific-node-attributes-in-networkx-with-python) your node attributes. Alternatively, as stated in [its documentation](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs), you can use OSMnx to dump your nodes to a geopandas GeoDataFrame and work with it pandas-style:

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, California, USA', network_type='drive')
nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, edges=False)
nodes[['x', 'y']]
```

The resulting `nodes` GeoDataFrame is indexed by OSM ID and contains `x` and `y` values representing the nodes' longitude and latitude. See also [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830767/check-which-edge-attributes-exist-networkx/44765586#44765586).

Comment: hi @gboeing, thank u for your work on osmnx. Is there any fast way to retrieve osm data for only 1 node. osmnx usually retrieves graph of an area, but I did not found any function for a single node. Thanks.